# Attach files using ckeditor (attachment and embed plugins missing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

We were using ckeditor gem [3.7.0](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/tree/1824cb49f10e6bcdb9b7bcb4396c3159c80e3448/vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins) until recently. And decide to upgrade to latest version of gem in order to support IE 10.

All is well, but it had two plugins (attachment and embed), which most of our customers are using. I have observed that they were removed while upgrading ckeditor plugin to 3.6.4 ([commit](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/commit/06f9c31145d2ed2e5b687629fc9eab88b33ae653))

Even in previous version (i.e., which uses 3.6.3 ckeditor plugin), code from official [repository](http://download.cksource.com/CKEditor/CKEditor/CKEditor%203.6.3/ckeditor_3.6.3.zip) doesn't contain these plugins.

Does anyone know how to get those plugins for ckeditor 4.x?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue once I upgraded to CKEditor 4.x and couldn't find the attachment source either. I ended up rewriting the attachment plugin to get it working.  I didn't use the embed plugin so did not rewrite that, but hopefully this helps with attachment.

Use this for attachment/plugin.js:

```
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'attachment', {
    icons: 'attachment',
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.addCommand( 'attachmentDialog', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'attachmentDialog') );
        editor.ui.addButton( 'attachment', {
            label: 'Document',
            command: 'attachmentDialog',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        });

        CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'attachmentDialog', this.path + 'dialogs/attachment.js' );
    }
}
```

Use this for attachment/dialogs/attachment.js:

```
    CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'attachmentDialog', function( editor ) {
    return {
        title: 'Upload Document',
        minWidth: 400,
        minHeight: 200,
        contents: [
            {
                id: 'general',
                label: 'Document Info',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'txtUrl',
                        label: 'URL',
                        validate: CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.notEmpty( "URL cannot be empty" )
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'button',
                        hidden: true,
                        id: 'browse',
                        filebrowser: 'general:txtUrl',
                        label: "Use Existing Document",
                        style: 'float:right',
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 'Upload',
                hidden: true,
                filebrowser: 'uploadButton',
                label: editor.lang.image.upload,
                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'file',
                        id: 'upload',
                        label: editor.lang.image.btnUpload,
                        style: 'height:40px',
                        size: 38
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'fileButton',
                        id: 'uploadButton',
                        filebrowser: 'general:txtUrl',
                        label: "Upload the Document",
                        'for': [ 'Upload', 'upload' ]
                    }
                ]
            },
        ],
        onOk: function() {
            var dialog = this;
            
            //Get the value selected in the editor.
            var selectedText = editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();
            
            var attachment = editor.document.createElement( 'a' );
            
            attachment.setAttribute( 'href', dialog.getValueOf( 'general', 'txtUrl' ) );
            
            //If there isn't anything selected in the editor, default the text to the document url.
            if (selectedText == "") {
                attachment.setText(dialog.getValueOf('general', 'txtUrl'));
            } else {
                attachment.setText(selectedText);
            }
            
            editor.insertElement(attachment);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the snippet. We have now encouraged our customers to use the upload option available in link popup. 
As for embed, we are now using iframe plugin.